# HTML: How to create a calendar view?

Tags: html, css, outlook, calendar

I am HTML/CSS beginner attempting to create calendar view very similar to Microsoft Outlook's design as shown below:

[image]

So far, I gotten the basic outline of the calendar with the following HTML/CSS:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>August, 2016</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center><h1>August, 2016</h1></center>
    <style>
        table{
            table-layout: fixed;
        }
    </style>
    <table border="1" width="1250" height="800">
        <tr>
            <th>Sun</th>
            <th>Mon</th>
            <th>Tue</th>
            <th>Wed</th>
            <th>Thur</th>
            <th>Fri</th>
            <th>Sat</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                                <a href="">Claim Benefits</a><br>
                                <a href="">Pick up groceries</a><br>
                                <a href="">Iron the shirts</a><br>
                                <a href="">+5 more...</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>9</td>
        </tr>
        </tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                                <a href="">Claim Benefits</a><br>
                                <a href="">Pick up groceries</a><br>
                                <a href="">Iron the shirts</a><br>
                                <a href="">+5 more...</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>9</td>
        </tr>
        </tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>9</td>
        </tr>
        </tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>9</td>
        </tr>
        </tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>9</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Which produces:

[image]
I want to accomplish some of the same things Outlook does:

1. The day of the month number should be on the top left corner of the cell. I attempted to create this with a table inside the cell but it doesn't quite feel or look right. I am directly attempting to recreate Outlook's view and the way they setup the day number and reminders below it.
2. Each of the cells should maintain the same size while containing up to 4 hyperlinks. In the above code, the cells of the row containing hyperlinks become bigger than the cells of the other rows. I want to fix the cell size such that all cells are the same size whether they contain up to 4 hyperlinks or not.

Thanks for any helpful code or suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. An easy way to position/style the calendar numbers separately from the content is to make them `td` pseudo-elements. You could set the content to something like `attr(data-day)` to have it dynamically display a number set in the HTML.
2. To make sure the cells have the same height, just specify a height in the CSS. Since you only want "up to 4 hyperlinks", you can just check what the height is for a cell with 4 links and then use that.

By the way, it looks like there are a lot of errors with the `tr` tags in your code, and I would recommend representing the listed elements inside an individual day as a list rather than as nested tables (the calendar is tabular data, but the contents of the day are a to-do list).

Here's a snippet that includes the recommended changes:

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 1250px;
  height: 800px;
}

table td {
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

table td:before {
  content: attr(data-day);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <h1>August, 2016</h1>
</center>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Sun</th>
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tue</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thur</th>
    <th>Fri</th>
    <th>Sat</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td data-day="1">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Claim Benefits</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Pick up groceries</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Iron the shirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="">+5 more...</a></li>
      </ul>
    </td>
    <td data-day="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-day="3"></td>
    <td data-day="4"></td>
    <td data-day="5"></td>
    <td data-day="6"></td>
    <td data-day="7"></td>
    <td data-day="8"></td>
    <td data-day="9"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-day="10"></td>
    <td data-day="11"></td>
    <td data-day="12">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Claim Benefits</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Pick up groceries</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Iron the shirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="">+5 more...</a></li>
      </ul>
    </td>
    <td data-day="13"></td>
    <td data-day="14"></td>
    <td data-day="15"></td>
    <td data-day="16"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-day="17"></td>
    <td data-day="18"></td>
    <td data-day="19"></td>
    <td data-day="20"></td>
    <td data-day="21"></td>
    <td data-day="22"></td>
    <td data-day="23"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-day="24"></td>
    <td data-day="25"></td>
    <td data-day="26"></td>
    <td data-day="27"></td>
    <td data-day="28"></td>
    <td data-day="29"></td>
    <td data-day="30"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-day="31"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I think You can add a `flot:left;` style to this month number, and maybe `margin,padding:0;`
2. I suggest to use `min-height` with the same value as height of all cells

Answer (score 0):

First, you have not added any styling so you are leaving that up to the browser's defaults. Also, the center tag is deprecated. Use this instead:

`h1 {text-align:center;}`

For the table, you can add this to make the border appear like Outlooks' borders:

`table, th, td {border-collapse: collapse;}`

To style the table data remove the padding and margin. That should move the first td in the first tr to the top left corner.

Lastly, add a specific height to the row of each week. I would assign that tr a class of week and style with whatever height you want:

`tr.week {height:200px;}`